# Sql out put which come into multiple row converted to single row

Tags: sql

[image]

This query give multiple row which needs to be shown in single row. Please help.

```
SELECT blng_serv_code, (COUNT (blng_serv_code)) AS total ,
         DECODE (package_trx_yn, 'Y', 'PKG', 'N', 'NPKG') pkg_status FROM bl_patient_charges_folio
   WHERE operating_facility_id = 'MC'
     AND trx_date >= TO_DATE ('10/10/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')AND blng_serv_code = 'LBSB000015'
GROUP BY blng_serv_code, package_trx_yn
```

Comment: Please [do not post code as images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value in a single row, leave out the package status:

```
SELECT blng_serv_code, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM bl_patient_charges_folio 
WHERE operating_facility_id = 'MC' AND
      trx_date >= DATE '2019-10-10' AND
      blng_serv_code = 'LBSB000015'
GROUP BY blng_serv_code;
```

If you do want the package status, then you need to explain the logic for including it "on a single row".

EDIT:

It sounds like you want the values in separate columns:

```
SELECT blng_serv_code, COUNT(*) AS total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN package_trx_yn = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pkg_cnt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN package_trx_yn = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as npkg_cnt
FROM bl_patient_charges_folio 
WHERE operating_facility_id = 'MC' AND
      trx_date >= DATE '2019-10-10' AND
      blng_serv_code = 'LBSB000015'
GROUP BY blng_serv_code;
```

Comment: This table 'bl_patient_charges_folio' has two columns 'blng_serv_code' and 'package_trx_yn' where I want to total count of column 'blng_serv_code' based on column value package_trx_yn = 'Y' and package_trx_yn = 'N'. If I used decode function then output is coming fine but it's splited into two rows. I want to be displayed in single row.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, second logic with case statement is worked fine for me.